# Why can you access enumerators outside the scope?

Tags: c++

Why can you access enumerators outside the scope, while you can’t directly access a structure’s members directly? By scope, I mean the declaration scope - Please correct me if I am wrong.

To give an example:
You can do this:

```
enum colors {red, blue, white};
int color = red;
```

but you cannot do this:

```
struct colors {red, blue, white};
int color = red;
```

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to expand this with some details, maybe an example of what you mean. Pretty much by definition, you can't access anything outside of its scope.

Comment: @CharlieMartin done.

Comment: Enums don't define a scope; they're just a list of constants, so you're not really accessing them "outside the scope". A struct is not a list of constants, but an object composed of multiple variables. [Scoped enums](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations), on the other hand...

Comment: Because the standard says so. It does so because that's the way it was in C. And that's all there is to say about this from a C++ perspective.

Comment: You can write `enum class colors  { red, blue, white };` and then the identifiers are scoped to the enum name

Comment: @Squidy, what do you mean by "define a scope"? Thanks guys!

Comment: or @CharlieMartin, maybe you know?

Comment: Okay, a "scope" is basically the part of a program in which a name is visible.  I'll add to my answer, comments don't do code well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, well, as another comment said, it's because that's the way C++ works.

Back in the old days, we simulated something like this with something like

```
class Colors {
  public:
    static int RED = 0;
    static int GREEN = 1;
    static int YELLOW = 2;
}
```

Then enum was added so you didn't need to write `Colors.RED`. It's essentially syntactic sugar.

**Update**

A *scope* is just the part of a program in which a name is visible. The rules can be simple, complicated or weird: C++ goes for complicated, JavaSccript goes for weird. You can see lengthy explanations [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm), but here's a basic notion.

In C++, which is a block-structured language that descended from Algol 60, a name is defined thoughout the block in which it's declared. One kind of block is the file. If a name is declared at the top of a file, it's defined everywhere in the file following the declaration.

Another kind of block is defined by a pair of braces `{}`.  Anything declared within braces is defined from the declaration up to the enclosing end brace.  So

```
#include <stdlib>  // copies a bunch of code into the file
int foo = 0;       // declared here, visible to end.

int fn(){
  int bar = 2 ;
  if(bar == 2){
    foo = bar;
    cout << bar << nl;  // gives '2'
    cout << foo << nl;  // still gives '2'
  }
  cout << foo << nl ;  // gives '0'
  cout << bar << nl ;  // compile time error 'bar' not defined
}
```

Why? the inner `foo` hides the outer `foo`, so that's the one that gets printed inside the `if` block. The `bar` is defined at the top of the `if` block, so it's no longer visible ("no longer in scope") after the brace ending the `if` block

There are more rules, but I'd recommend reading about it in one of those links or a good C++ book.

Comment: Thanks man! But so would you say that "bar" is only visible in the scope of the fn funciton, or would you say that "bar" is only visible within the block of bar? Thanks again! I really like you answer

Comment: Whoops, you have actually linked the answer to my question :)

Comment: Thanks. You've been a wonderful audience, don't forget to tip your server.

Comment: Oh, and the answer to your question is "yes". I might say it either way, depending on what I was trying to emphasize, the preceding conversation, and the phase of the moon. "scope of bar" is the more technically correct answer though.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a scope to be outside of. `enum` doesn't introduce a new scope in the way that `struct` does. Why? Well, why not. They are two entirely different things, so expecting one to work the same as the other is vacuous.

`enum class`, however, *does* work that way; the feature is aptly called "scoped enums".